# how can I refrain from using same vocabularies. "The cook cooks meal"

Tags: word-choice

Here is example.

In this Hotel, "The cook cooks" meal everyday.

We have a scale to "weigh the weight".

while I'm typing it, I can understand something is weird in the sentences but
I couldn't find the other alternatives.

is this ok to use these kind of words which almost came from same root of vocabulary? if it is not natural, what else will be an answer?

Comment: Use a thesaurus, and increase your exposure to English by reading more (long form works, ideally).

Comment: It's not wrong, but it's good to avoid, by rewording somehow.  As Dan suggests, a thesaurus can be of considerable help.

Comment: tp prepare, to check

Comment: A scale measures mass, not weight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can be OK. It can sometimes be used to great effect for emphasis. However, it is easy to rephrase if you wish to do so:

> The cook prepares a meal every day.
>
> The cook sees to our meals every day.
>
> The chef cooks a meal everyday.

The second is easier since your example is actually wrong. You don't weigh weights unless you have put metal wights on a scale and are trying to weigh *them*. Normally, you would say something like

> We have a scale to measure weight.
>
> We have a scale for weighing.
>
> We have a scale to weigh our grain.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. It is very helpful for understanding.

Comment: @lizard99 you're very welcome. If this answer solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left. That will mark the question as answered and is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites.